# Calculating median across multiple rows and columns in SAS 9.4

Tags: sas, median

I tried searching multiple places but have not been able to find a solution yet. I was wondering if someone here would be able to please help me?

I am trying to calculate a median value (with Q1 and Q3) across multiple rows and columns in SAS 9.4 The dataset I am working with looks like the following:

```
Obs tumor_size_1 tumor_size_2 tumor_size_3 tumor_size_4
1   4            1.5          1            1
2   2.5          2            .            .
3   3            .            .            .
4   4            .            .            .
5   3.5          1            .            .
```

The context is this is for a medical condition where a person may have 1 (or more) tumors. Each row represents 1 person. Each person may have up to 4 tumors. I would like to determine the median size of all tumors for the entire cohort (not just the median size for each person). Is there a way to calculate this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transpose of the data will yield a data structure (form) that is amenable to median and quartile computations, at a variety of aggregate combinations, made with `PROC SUMMARY` and a `CLASS` statement.

Example:

```
data have;
input
patient tumor_size_1 tumor_size_2 tumor_size_3 tumor_size_4; datalines;
1   4            1.5          1            1
2   2.5          2            .            .
3   3            .            .            .
4   4            .            .            .
5   3.5          1            .            .
;

proc transpose data=have out=new_have;
by patient;
var tumor:;
run;

proc summary data=new_have;
  class patient;
  var col1;
  output out=want Q1=Q1 Q3=Q3 MEDIAN=MEDIAN N=N;
run;
```

Results

```
patient    _TYPE_    _FREQ_    Q1     Q3     MEDIAN     N

   .          0        20       1    3.50     2.25     10
   1          1         4       1    2.75     1.25      4
   2          1         4       2    2.50     2.25      2
   3          1         4       3    3.00     3.00      1
   4          1         4       4    4.00     4.00      1
   5          1         4       1    3.50     2.25      2
```

The `_TYPE_` column describes the ways in which the `CLASS` variables are combined in order to achieve the results for the requested statistics.  The `_TYPE_ = 0` case is for all values, and, in this problem, the `_FREQ_ = 20` indicates 20 inputs went into the computation consideration, and that `N = 10` of those were non-missing and were involved in the actual computation.  The role of `_TYPE_` becomes more obvious when there is more than one `CLASS` variable.

From the [Output Data Set](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetVersion=9.4&docsetTarget=n026epq8bpz1f9n10oeb7zen7s1e.htm&locale=en) documentation:

> > - the variable _TYPE_ that contains information about the class variables. By default _TYPE_ is a numeric variable. If you specify CHARTYPE in the PROC statement, then _TYPE_ is a character variable. When you use more than 32 class variables, _TYPE_ is automatically a character variable.

and

> > The value of _TYPE_ indicates which combination of the class variables PROC MEANS uses to compute the statistics. The character value of _TYPE_ is a series of zeros and ones, where each value of one indicates an active class variable in the type. For example, with three class variables, PROC MEANS represents type 1 as 001, type 5 as 101, and so on.

A far less elegant way to compute the median of all is to store all the values in an oversized array and use the `MEDIAN` function on the array after the last row is read in:

```
data median_all;
  set have end=lastrow;
  array values [1000000] _temporary_;
  array sizes tumor_size_1-tumor_size_4;

  do sIndex = 1 to dim(sizes);
/*    if not missing (sizes[sIndex]) then do; */  %* decomment for dense fill;
      vIndex + 1;
      values[vIndex] = sizes[sIndex];
/*    end; */                                     %* decomment for dense fill;
  end;

  if lastrow then do;
    median_all_tumor_sizes = median (of values(*));
    output;
    put (median:) (=);
  end;

  keep median:;
run;

-------- LOG -------
median_all_tumor_sizes=2.25
```

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for your thoughtful response. I apologize but I think my original post was too ambiguous. What I'm hoping to do is to calculate a median tumor size that is averaged for every tumor measured in the dataset (i.e., across all rows and cols). So, for the example above, I would like to have a single summary statistic for all values and all patients, (i.e., median = 2.25 for the values 4, 1.5, 1, 1, 2.5, 2, 3, 4, 3.5, and Q1 = 1.125, and Q3 = 2.875), rather than an individual median for each patient. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Alex the output you're after is in the first row. If you don't want the per-patient output then just delete `class patient;` from the final proc.

Comment: @user667489 thank you very much for the clarification!

Comment: @Richard I really appreciate your help! With much gratitude, Alex